# How to solve Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:2133000 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, xhtml2pdf

I am using django, celery and xhtml2pdf to generate pdfs. Small size pdf are created but when pdf size gets larger and few images is added. I get following error.
`Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:2133000 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'`
Can somebody help to solve this?

Comment: The simplest solution: Add more memory to your machine.